# Struct inside C++ 'struct name' does not name a type

Tags: c++, struct

A.h

```
class A {
  enum E {one , two , three};
  struct B {
      char a;
      E num;
  };

  static const B arr[];
}
```

A.cpp

```
const B A::arr[] = {
  {'1', one},
  {'2', two},
  {'3', three}
};
```

I get the following error while compiling:
'B' does not name a type

Answer (score 6):

`B` is defined in the scope of `A`, so you need to refer to it by its full name:

```
const A::B A::arr[] = { ....
```

Comment: @mariner, if the answer helps you then try to accept it.